# Calculate delta in percentage in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate delta in percentage. I have come up with this function. Is this the correct one?

```
var a = 300;
var b = 400;
var res;
res = Math.abs(a - b) / a
```

Is there a complete function that has defense against zeros?

Thank you

Comment: "that has defense against zeros" --- what does it mean?

Comment: "Is this the correct one?" --- if it returns a correct result, then it's correct. Otherwise it's not.

Comment: If either variable a or b has a zero value.

Comment: You check if a variable is zero with `if`

Comment: Yes, I can check it with if, but I was wondering is there a complete function already, so I dont reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: In this case there is no, since the problem is not generic enough.

Comment: Assuming "a" is the old value and "b" the new one, the function is correct.
Source: http://www.annielytics.com/blog/excel-tips/easiest-way-to-calculate-percent-delta-in-excel/

Comment: `res = a ? Math.abs(a - b) / a : 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one liner is

```
res = a && Math.abs(a - b) / a;
```

Answer (score 1):

A one liner is `a && Math.abs(a - b) / a || 0`

Comment: or just `a ? Math.abs(a - b) / a : 0`